Pebble dropped on a stationary pond with a non-perpendicular angle of impact to help conceptualize the Michelson-Morley experiment
I am trying to better understand the logic behind the famed 1887 Michelson-Morley experiment...and want to comprehend what they EXPECTED to see. As I understand it, the motivation behind this experimental setup was, under the initial assumption that the Aether existed, to detect differences of traversal speeds of different light beams (propagating as waves) as a consequence of the Earth moving through said Aether.
To help me conceptualize this, I wanted to refer to the commonly analogized dropping a pebble onto a stationary pond. By utilizing this analogy, it seemed more accurate to portray the Aether as the non-moving pond and the pebble as the Earth but with a non-perpendicular angle of impact, easily depicted in the below drawing:

At the point of contact with the pond's surface, the imparted force could be described in its decomposed vector form as:

Idealizing all other considerations (rock shape, etc), is it correct to say that the resulting wave propagation on the water's surface in the direction of $F_x$ is 1) faster and 2) has a reduced spatial frequency (i.e. more physical distance between each peak) than the wave propagation in the antiparallel direction? Although I am unsure about what the amplitudes of each
direction's ripple would look like, after some time $t$, we would have something like:

Is this the right idea? Or am I completely off the mark?

I think you are overthinking your example, it's better to drop the pebble to create the waves, then simply walk along the shore observing that the relative speed of the ripples change as you adjust your pace.

@Triatticus ahhh, that makes a lot more sense. Though, I guess in this case, the observer on the shoreline is the earth and the pebble is simply some sort of 'wave source'. Thank you very much!


is it correct to say that the resulting wave propagation on the water's surface in the direction of $F_x$
is 1) faster and 2) has a reduced spatial frequency (i.e. more physical distance between each peak) than the wave propagation in the antiparallel direction?

No.  The speed of propagation through the medium (in the frame where the medium is at rest) is mostly constant and doesn't depend on the direction of the initial disturbance.
The waves propagating in both directions have the same disturbance/frequency and move at the same speed (again, assuming we're in the frame where the medium is at rest).   Therefore by $c = f\lambda$, they have the same distance between peaks.
But if you are not in the frame where the medium is at rest, then the relative speed of the waves as they pass you depend on the direction they are moving.

TL;DR: pretty much, that's how the MM experiment went down
The expected result of the MM interferometer experiment (notably, the one they didn't observe) was that the two legs would interfere with each other because they would be out of phase; this would be due to the anisotropy of the speed of light along each leg. Along one, it would travel faster and reach the detector with a certain phase; along the other, it would travel slower and reach the detector with a different phase.
They postulated that the reason that this would occur is because the aether is moving - we aren't immediately at rest in the luminiferous aether, and if the medium is moving, so are the particles within. But it turns out that there was no interference observed (because relativity is real and dictates that light moves at precisely the same speed in all frames of reference).

I guess the pond analogy you give is reasonable. Obviously you'd need to consider higher dimensions than just the pond but it's not necessarily a wrong way to think about it. The angle at which the pebble is thrown would be the velocity of the luminiferous aether (or related to it through some trigonometric relation); it would be primarily the frequency of the resulting water waves that would be looked at in an MM experiment, but not necessarily the amplitude.
With that in mind the MM experiment's results would essentially be that it didn't seem to matter which direction you threw the pebble, it always lands at precisely 90 degrees when it hits the pond. That's contradictory with the pond actually even existing, since the pond can't magically rotate to match any trajectory of pebble (hence, no luminiferous aether).

dictates that light moves at precisely the same speed in all frames of reference - it doesn't require that. A characteristic of the Lorentzian view is that the OWSOL can vary whilst the TWSOL remains constant - this is exactly how it reconciles the existence of an aether (a wave medium) with the available evidence.

There is no aether, though - any observer always observes photons to move at $c$ in flat spacetime, no matter their velocity relative to anything.

Well, the aether is still consistent with current scientific evidence. An observer can only observe TWSOL by known methods, so whether the OWSOL varies or not is an open scientific question.

I am not aware of any such evidence. That would imply an apparently-anisotropic speed of light depending on reference frame (due to a priviledged frame), which is precisely what the MM experiment ruled out.

You must be aware that no current evidence has falsified the theory? Lorentz, Einstein, JS Bell, prominent physicists like these have all said it remains current science. The MM experiment didn't rule out anisotropic OWSOL - as there's no currently-known method to measure it.

Russel's Teapot: it is not on the community to falsify your claim, it is on you to prove it. Provide evidence for an aether, and the community will then believe you. I'd be hard-pressed to find a reasonable cosmologist/physicist who believes than an aether exists. (And the OWSOL stuff is not actually related to the aether at all. Lorentz invariance requires the nonexistence of an aether.)

The evidence supporting the theory of an aether is all the evidence currently available. I've just listed three physicists who held that the theory of an aether remained current science. As for "Lorentz invariance", you do realise that's the same Lorentz who derived his work on relativity by analysing EM as something mediated by a wave medium called the "aether"?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
